# Как поменять местами ключи внутри ассоциативного массива php?

Tags: php

Как с помощью цикла foreach поменять местами ключи?

$arr = ['Сидоров' => 'Petya', 'Ким' => 'Vasya', 'Иванов' => 'Kolya', 'Петров' =>'Gene', 'Сика' =>'Jenya'];

for ($i = 0, $count = count($arr); $i < $count; $i++) {

}

Comment: Если в том же массиве - то никак. Нужен новый массив и цикл foreach

Comment: спасибо за подсказку. сейчас попробую foreach

Comment: foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) $arr2[$v] = $k

Comment: @Jour спасибо. у меня получился вот такой вариант $arr = ['Сидоров' => 'Petya', 'Ким' => 'Vasya', 'Иванов' => 'Kolya', 'Петров' =>'Gene', 'Сика' =>'Jenya'];
$result = [];


foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $result[$value] = isset( $result[$value] ) ? "{$result[$value]},{$key}" : $key;
}

var_dump($result);